# laravel4 How can i use eloquent in my controller?

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent, relationship

I would like to create a relationship between 2 tables with eloquent but i can't find exactly how to proceed...

Here are my 2 models with relationship :

Table "etablissement":

```
<?php class Etablissement extends Eloquent {
/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'etablissement';

public function annulation()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Annulation');
}}
```

Table "annulation":

```
<?php class Annulation extends Eloquent {
/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'annulation_remboursement';

public function etablissement ()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Etablissement');
}}
```

In the "Etablissement" table there is an id for each etablissement (id_etablissement) and in the "annulation" there is a column with the id_etablissement. How can i return in my controller a relation in order to have the etablissement's name with the annulation->id_etablissement :

```
class AnnulationsController extends \BaseController {

/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function index()
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this within your `index` method:

```
$annulation = Annulation::find(1);

$annulation->etablissement->name
```

The `annulation_remboursement` table should have a `establissement_id` field.

Comment: Thanks for this answer but i get an error : Trying to get property of non-object... Any idea?

Comment: Just make sure you are testing an `annulation` row which has an existing etablissement.

Comment: Yes, if i did var_dump($annulation->etablissement_id) it works, i can have the result like (7501).

Comment: What does show `dd($annulation->etablissement->id)`?

Comment: Same error, "Trying to get property of non-object".

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the error may be in the keys of the relation.

In https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#one-to-one we see:

> Take note that Eloquent assumes the foreign key of the relationship based on the model name. In this case, Phone model is assumed to use a user_id foreign key. If you wish to override this convention, you may pass a second argument to the hasOne method. Furthermore, you may pass a third argument to the method to specify which local column that should be used for the association:
>
> return $this->hasOne('Phone', 'foreign_key');
>
> return $this->hasOne('Phone', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
>
> [...] **One To Many**: Again, you may override the conventional foreign key by passing a second argument to the hasMany method. And, like the hasOne relation, the local column may also be specified:
>
> return $this->hasMany('Comment', 'foreign_key');
>
> return $this->hasMany('Comment', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');

* *You should also checkout **Defining The Inverse Of A Relation** at the same page.*

So, in your case you have a key named `id_etablissement` but Laravel is searching for `etablissement_id`. If you wish to override this behaviour and specify a key you should do something like:

```
protected $table = 'etablissement';
public function annulation()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Annulation','id_etablissement');
}
```

and according to "The Inverse Of A Relation"

```
protected $table = 'annulation_remboursement';
public function etablissement ()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Etablissement','id_etablissement');
}
```

Note that I didn't put any of the local keys, but those will be the third parameter of the relation.